# Can't open video by OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'm trying to open a video by OpenCV version 3.1.0 on visual studio 2015.My program simply opens a video. It works in opencv version 2.4 and visual studio 2010. I have no idea to fix this:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include<iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{

    VideoCapture cap("C:/Users/NguyenVanDung/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/ReadingVideo/ReadingVideo/walk.avi"); // open the default camera
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        cout << "can't read video" << endl;
        system("pause");        // check if we succeeded
        return -1;
    }  
    Mat edges;
    namedWindow("edges", 1);

    for (;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        imshow("edges", frame);
        if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output : 
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\NguyenVanDung\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ReadingVideo\x64\Debug\ReadingVideo.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Av\avghooka.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\opencv_world310d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\FirewallAPI.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\netapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.10586.0_none_396e892957c7fb25\comctl32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvfw32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avifil32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avicap32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\concrt140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\davhlpr.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\fwbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.

***** VIDEOINPUT LIBRARY - 0.1995 - TFW07 *****

'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iyuv_32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iyuv_32.dll'
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iyuv_32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iyuv_32.dll'
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msrle32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msrle32.dll'
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvidc32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvidc32.dll'
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msyuv.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msyuv.dll'
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msyuv.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msyuv.dll'
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\tsbyuv.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\tsbyuv.dll'
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msyuv.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msyuv.dll'
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iyuv_32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iyuv_32.dll'
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iyuv_32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iyuv_32.dll'
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msrle32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msrle32.dll'
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvidc32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvidc32.dll'
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msyuv.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msyuv.dll'
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msyuv.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msyuv.dll'
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\tsbyuv.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\tsbyuv.dll'
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msyuv.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadingVideo.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msyuv.dll'
The program '[12640] ReadingVideo.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Comment: Please don't call it "your" program when you took the code from someone else....

Comment: What's the used encoding of the video? can you try different video files?

Comment: I try 2 kinds of video  mp4, avi  but they have the same results

Comment: avi doesn't tell anything about the encoding. OpenCV doesn't support all kinds of codecs, especially on windows.

Comment: Where can I find the codec of the video?

Comment: your program doesn't compile or is it unable to find/open the video file.

Comment: my suggestions are
1- verify the file is actually present in the path  speciefied
2- use \\ instead of / in your program e.g C:/Users/NguyenVanDung... should be C:\\Users\\NguyenVanDung\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\ReadingVideo\\ReadingVideo\\walk.avi

Comment: I just reinstalled visual studio 2013 and opencv 3.1.0 and It works. I don't understand why :D